# Затемнение фона

Tags: c#, uwp

Как сделать что при нажатии куда нибудь(например открыл SpilitView панель, или FlyoutMenu) и задний фон затемнился?

Comment: в обработчике события нажатия сделать необходимые манипуляции с фоном